# Convert curl http post command to cold fusion post command

Tags: curl, cfhttp

Can someone provide assistance on how to convert this curl http post command to cfhttp (cold fusion) post command.

Currently this command works using **curl**:

```
curl.exe -k -w %%{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -u f7c1b455-9128-4768-aaaa-3d5cb0e79c82:l3tm31n --data-binary @C:\temp\vhs.students.txt https://server1.ctdlc.org/webapps/bb-data-integration-flatfile-BBLEARN/endpoint/person/store
```

However I need to convert it over to using cold fusion. 
This command below executes but seems to be changing the contents of the file or the file is not reaching the destination. Any help is appreciated.

> cfhttp method="post" url="https://bbtest5.ctdlc.org/webapps/bb-data-integration-flatfile-BBLEARN/endpoint/person/store" 
>   username="f7c1b455-9128-4768-a7ef-3d5cb0e79c82" password="password">
>   cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/plain">
>   cfhttpparam type="file" file="G:\CF11webnoaccess\ctvhs\blackboard\vhs.students.txt"  name="vhs.students.txt"> 
>   < /cfhttp>

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you would read and follow the instructions over at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! you can make the code parts of your question look nice by either enclosing it in backticks (`) or use four spaces to indent it, as i've suggested for an edit in your post.

Comment: Yeah, what do you mean by "contents of the file or the file is not reaching the destination"?  How do you know its changning, at what point is it changing. Do you see the request failing? How are you sure its sending?